# How to find out the port number of a TCP connection

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have the following piece of code.

```
server = TCPServer.new(3200)
client = server.accept()
```

How do I find out what port number that client sent its message to me is? I have tried both client.peeraddr and client.addr and both of them do not give me the proper port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port that clients are connecting to is 3200. And port on client side where connection is created from is random for every connection, given by OS from unused ports.

Answer (score 1):

[`client.peeraddr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/IPSocket.html#method-i-peeraddr) gives you an array that corresponds to a `struct addrinfo`.  For AF_INET, it looks something like this:

```
["AF_INET", 48942, "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"]
```

You can create an [Addrinfo](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Addrinfo.html) object from it and get the port like so:

```
require 'socket'
server = TCPServer.new(3200)
client = server.accept()
addr = Addrinfo.new(client.peeraddr)
port = addr.ip_port
```